# How does android:taskaffinity work?

Tags: android, taskaffinity

How does `android:taskaffinity` attribute work?

As per my understanding, pressing the Home key will move the activity to back stack, but it will not be destroyed. I am confused.

Answer (score -1):

You indeed set a diffrent android:taskAffinity for activity2 and for the other activities. This will force android to make a diffrent stack when (see my example).

```
 <activity android:name=".activity2" android:taskAffinity="com.example.act2" >
 </activity>

 <activity android:name=".activity1" android:taskAffinity="com.example.act1" >
 </activity>
```

The following sequence should be correct. for the

1. Start activity2.
2. press Home
3. Start activity1.
4. Press back -> the homescreen should be showed.